# Full Calendar double click dialog and add event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to add a function to my fullcalendar where by when I double click, a dialog will pop out and allow me to add event. However the code I used below doesnt work as it is when I double click nothing happen.  How do I achieve when I double click any day and a dialog box will popout and allowing me to add an event to the day?

```
 eventClick: function() { 
            $("#cal_event").dialog({
                   title: calEvent.title
             });
       }
```

So I did some example on alert, when I click on any day in the calendar the alert box will pop out.

```
   dayClick: function() {

    alert('click');



}
```

Comment: you dont need double click full calendar has click event already

Comment: @guradio Sorry but how do I set it, currently my raw calendar has no function whatsoever. When I click on any day nothing happen

Comment: Is this link helpfull? https://www.alinous.org/web-developer/software-test/testing-fullcalendar.html

Comment: what you have is sufficient. what is happening when you click?

Comment: @guradio nothing happen, I am reading the site given by webbie now, hopeing to see some light around it. I am pretty new to javascript